# Skimming stones vs skipping stones?

Tags: expressions

I heard someone talked about "skimming stones" but read in a book about "stone skipping".

Is one from the US and the other from the UK ?
Is there **any difference** or do they have the **exact same meaning** ?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to EL&U. Interesting question. :)

Comment: They are the [same](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skimming_stones) thing.

Comment: Doesn't Sir Elton John sing a song with the words "skimming stones"? I think the name of the song is "Crocodile Rock."

Comment: @rhetorician: [He did indeed!](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/eltonjohn/crocodilerock.html) Obviously ***Sir** Elton John* is a Brit, but it's interesting that he used the almost exclusively British verb in a song that was (presumably, intentionally) predominantly "American" in tone. We don't drive ***Chevies***, and we don't say things like *"**Oh Lawdy mama!**"* as in the lyrics of that "mixed parentage" song.

Comment: I want to thank all of you for your answers which were all very clear and useful !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They mean the same, but there's a significant US/UK split. [Here's the US usage...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=skipping%20stones,skimming%20stones&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,skipping%20stones;,c0;.t1;,skimming%20stones;,c0)

[image]

...and [here's the UK usage...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=skipping%20stones,skimming%20stones&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,skipping%20stones;,c0;.t1;,skimming%20stones;,c0)

[image]

But whereas I personally would invariably refer to the activity itself as *skimming stones*, I see nothing unusual in [this BBC piece from a few years ago...](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/magazine/7022464.stm)

> *How do you **skim** a stone 51 times?
>
>   Russell "Rock Bottom" Byars has **skimmed** his way into the record books, throwing a stone that **skipped** an amazing 51 times.*

I would always say the *pastime* (what the *person* does) is *skimming*, but to me it's perfectly reasonable to refer to what the *stone* does as *skipping* (and to call each bounce a *skip*, not a *skim*).

Comment: I guess I must side squarely with the Americans on this one. ‘Skimming stones’ to me sounds like something only an extremely bad cook would ever have to do.

Comment: @Janus: I think I've said this before - your user profile here doesn't specify location. But I'm guessing it's not the UK. The "adjectival" usage ***skipping** stones* doesn't sound quite so odd to my British ear - like my cited BBC reporter, I'm happy to say what the *stone* does can be called ***skipping***. But to me, what the *person* did was [skimmed a stone](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=skimmed+a+stone%2Cskipped+a+stone&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cskimmed%20a%20stone%3B%2Cc0) (no instances at all of BrE "skipped" there).

Comment: The stones/pebbles *skim* the surface of the water. Would *bounce* work as well?

Comment: You’re right, it’s not the UK—it’s Copenhagen. Which I suppose is a big part of the reason why my dialectal belonging in English is so random: half the time I find myself siding with the Brits, half the time I find myself siding with the Americans, and half the time I find myself wondering whom I actually _do_ side with.

Comment: @Janus: On the plus side though, you're probably more likely to actually *think* about those differences which you must inevitably be aware of at least sometimes. I suspect most Americans aren't even exposed to much BrE, and many Brits tend to dismiss AmE variants as "uneducated" or "slang" - a parochialism you're probably less likely to be carried away by.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: *Bounce* is a perfectly suitable word in this context - I used it myself in the final parenthetical point in my answer, and it occurs twice in the relatively short BBC piece I quoted from.

Comment: @Fumble, absolutely—plus, being in general a linguophile helps me to do that even better. I often find myself almost shocked when Americans don’t even know what some fairly common, basic BrE expression means (like ‘snog’ or ‘faff about’, both of which I’ve met Americans who didn’t understand at all), or vice versa (rarer). :-)

Comment: @Janus: I think by now enough Americans have sniggered about *Brits with fags in their mouths* that they realise we're not all homosexuals with a penchant for fellatio. But mostly they don't know UK *pissed = merry = well-oiled* as opposed to US *pissed = angry = provoked*. Linguistically, we continue to plough a lonely furrow.

Comment: When I think of skimming and a body of open water, I think of the Black Skimmer—a ternlike bird that skims the surface of placid coastal waters, with its unusually elongated lower beak partially submerged in the water. Wikipedia identifies three species of skimmer—one in Africa, one in India, and one in North and South America. Our bird most certainly doesn't bounce as it skims. This URL leads to an excellent picture of one in action: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Black_Skimmer_by_Dan_Pancamo.jpg

Answer (score 2):

They are the same.

[skimming stones](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/skim): to throw in a smooth, gliding path over or near a surface, or so as to bounce or ricochet along a surface:

> ...skimmed a stone across the lake.

[skipping stones](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/skip):to ricochet or bounce along a surface:

> The stone skipped over the lake.

North America: "skipping rocks" or "skipping stones" (Wiki)

Answer (score 0):

We use the term SKIMMING in Australia.  Skipping stones doesn't sound right to an Australian Ear.

Yana

Answer (score 0):

The word ***skip*** was used in *The Dam Busters* (1955), to refer to a bomb [skipping over the water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dam_Busters_(film))

> In the early years of the Second World War, aeronautical engineer
>   Barnes Wallis is struggling to develop a means of attacking Germany's
>   dams in the hope of crippling German heavy industry. Working for the
>   Ministry of Aircraft Production, as well as doing his own job at
>   Vickers, he works feverishly to make practical his theory of a
>   bouncing bomb which would **skip** over the water to avoid protective
>   torpedo nets.  (emphasis added)

Other answers have made it clear that either skim or skip can be used for mere stones, but for bombs, it's [skip-bombing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_bombing).

Answer (score -1):

When I was a child in Norfolk in the 1940s/50s we talked about playing 'ducks and drakes'. I still  call it that and am glad to see that Wiktionary recognises it.

But the whole question of assigning expressions as American or British is I believe fundamentally flawed. It seems to me that in Britain we are far less inclined to name things. In America it would appear that almost every practice has an official name. I once explained to an American that we had been out in the car and had taken some food to eat. 'Ah, you had a tail-gate picnic', he said. So in the USA even such a random practice as sitting on the rear bumper of your car eating a sandwich means you are doing something which has an official name assigned to it. I actually find this slightly claustrophobic.

Sometimes, when in America, I will use an expression which has just come into my head from nowhere and someone will say 'Oh, so that's what you say in Britain is it' - Er, no, it is just what I said 30 seconds ago!

Comment: I'm not going to update this because it's really more of an extended comment than an answer to the specific question. But I'm very much inclined to agree with the overall sentiment, which I think in part may reflect the fact that *until now*, there has probably always been a higher percentage of Americans who aren't fully confident that their English is good enough (specifically, non-native speakers, or the children thereof). That may all change in the coming decades, as the demographic profile of the UK changes with massively increased immigration.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your comment is apposite. But I also think the language feature is merely a microcosm of American society in general. Though I have no evidence for this I sense, for example, that a higher proportion of ready-meals are eaten in America than in Britain. Fast-food, chain restaurants, internet selling are similar features. Americans are  prepared to accept higher levels of standardisation, which regrettably we are copying. Advantages include more consistency of quality, disadvantages - a frustration in creativity. This is especially so, I find, with language.

Comment: I've heard of tailgaiting, and I've heard of picnicking, but this American wouldn't call "sitting on the rear bumper of your car eating a sandwich" either one of those. Shame to take one anecdote and generalize in so sweeping a fashion.

Comment: @Susan. May I suggest you read 'Fast Food Nation' by Eric Schlosser. There are people who only ever eat fast food, from a standard menu, 365 days of the year. I suppose whether you chose a Desperate Dan Burger or a Cheesey Whopper (I've no idea what they are really called), and whether you put salt on your chips, involves some level of creativity.

Comment: @J.R According to Wikipedia there is no second 'i' in 'tailgating'.

Comment: @WS2: Of course not; _tailgate_ is the verb. Unfortuntately, I make typos every now and then, and unfortunately, I can't fix them after 5 minutes.

Comment: [Tailgating](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1024&bih=724&q=tailgate+party&oq=tailgate&gs_l=img.1.2.0l10.912.2822.0.7526.8.6.0.2.2.0.83.382.6.6.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..0.8.391.w1t_dcs_IvQ) is a social phenomenon. It is *not* the mere happenstance of "taking some food in the car" or "sitting on the rear bumper of your car eating a sandwich". (And it is not an "official" word in any regard.) It comes from (a) the common need to park many cars in a parking lot for a sporting event (or other large event) and (b) the desire to eat and drink before the game.